# Border does not fill/surround the container

Tags: html, css

I have added the following code:

```
    .sp-image-container {
    border-style: solid; 
    border-color: #FFDA67;
    border-width: 3px;
}
```

To the site www.dennissoderkvist.dk

As you see there is a slider with a border. But the border does not surround the container. I'm out of options on how to fix this. I want the entire frame to have the border color that I specified in the CSS.

Comment: maybe an `overflow:hidden` ? or `box-sizing:border-box` ?

Comment: I tried overflow:hidden already, nothing changed :(

Comment: then try the other option ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
.sp-image-container {
  border-style: solid; 
  border-color: #FFDA67;
  border-width: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[More info on box-sizing.](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

At any rate, the `div` with the border has the same dimensions as its parent `div`, so that's why adding a border to the child `div` is spilling over.

Comment: That did it, thanks a lot. I will accept your answer when I'm allowed by the system